SXA language emabedding
I'm working on an SXA multilingual site and have set the language embedding option to "always." I've also added the source and destination URLs.
Example below

I've accessed our business page (http://localhost:3000/en/our-business), but it redirects to the about us page without the language code in the URL (http://localhost:3000/about-us).
My issue is that the about us page should redirect with the language code included.
please can anyone help on this.

The default Next.js behaviour is to ignore the language embedding for default language. You can use the i18n section of the next.config.js to create a default language as default. It will embed the language then.
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['default', 'en', 'de', 'fr'],
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
}

Please refer to this documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#prefixing-the-default-locale

By default, en language in the url is the default locale and it is skipped. In order to modify this you can set the default locale as default inside the next.config.js file as below.
i18n: {
    // These are all the locales you want to support in your application.
    // These should generally match (or at least be a subset of) those in Sitecore.
    locales: ['default', 'en', 'en-US'],
    // This is the locale that will be used when visiting a non-locale
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    localeDetection: false,
},

Using above changes, will make sure en is not removed in the language url's. Make sure to changes the locales property as well, as mentioned above.
More details on the Internationalization(i18n) routing can be found here.
Hope this helps!!!

To resolve the issue of language embedding in SXA for your multilingual site, you can configure your Next.js application to prefix the default locale in the URLs. This ensures that when a user accesses a page, the URL includes the appropriate language code, even for redirects.
Configure next.config.js:
In your Next.js application, you can set up internationalization (i18n) in your next.config.js file. Here's an example configuration:
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    localeDetection: false, // Optional: disable automatic detection
  },
};

Prefix Default Locale:
To ensure that the default locale is always prefixed in the URL, you can modify the next.config.js as follows:
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    localeDetection: false,
    // Force default locale in URL
    localePath: true,
  },
};

By enabling this option, when accessing the home page, the URL will look like http://localhost:3000/en instead of just http://localhost:3000.
For further details, you can refer to the official Next.js documentation on internationalization here.
